# Determine the circle that is tangent to three given ellipses

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles, conic-sections

Given three ellipses in the plane specified as follows

$(r - C_1)^T Q_1 (r - C_1) = 1$,

$(r - C_2)^T Q_2 (r - C_2) = 1$

$(r - C_3)^T Q_3 (r - C_3) = 1$

I want to find the circle that is externally tangent to all three ellipses.

**My attempt:** is detailed in my solution below.

Your comments on both the question and the answer are valuable to me, and highly appreciated, so are your answers.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible in general. A circle has three degrees of freedom, its radius, and the two coordinates of its center. Where it is tangent to two ellipses, their are equations matching their tangents, and tangents between their points of intersection. So that's 4 equations and 3 unknowns just from two ellipses. Consequently I would think it can only be tangent to specific third ellipses but not in general. Could be missing something.

Comment: The coordinates of the three tangency points are to be added to the circle parameters, so that's $9$ unknowns.  For each of the three ellipses you can write two equations, and then for the circle you can an additional $3$ equations relating the radius to the distance betwen the center of the circle and each of the tangency point with the ellipses, so its $9$ equations in $9$ unknowns.  In my solution, I've eliminated the radius of the circle, so that it is defined implicitly (these are the last two equations in my solution).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the equations of the three ellipses can be written as follows:

$ r^T Q_1 r + b_1^T r + c_1 = 0 $

$ r^T Q_2 r + b_2^T r + c_2 = 0 $

$ r^T Q_3 r + b_3^T r + c_3 = 0 $

where $ b_i = - 2 Q_i C_i $, and $c_i = C_i^T Q_i C_i - 1 $.

Let $r_1$ , $r_2$ , and $r_3$ be the tangency points between the circle to be found and the three ellipses respectively, and let $C_4$ be the center of the circle.  Then the following $8$ equations can be written.  The first three state that these points belong to the respective ellipses:

$ r_i^T Q_i r_i + b_i^T r_1 + c_i = 1, i = 1,2,3 $

The next three state that

$ (r_i - C_4) = \alpha_i ( 2 Q_i r_i + b_i ) , i=1,2,3 $

Therefore, if anti-symmetric matrix $E$ is defined as

$ E = e_1 e_2^T - e_2 e_1^T

Then, we will have

$ (r_i - C_4)^T E (2 Q_i r_i + b_i) = 0 , i = 1, 2, 3$

And finally

$(r_1 - C_4)^T (r_1 - C_4) = (r_2 - C_4)(r_2 - C_4) $

and

$(r_1 - C_4)^T (r_1 - C_4) = (r_3 - C_4) (r_3 - C_4)$

These are $8$ quadratic equations in $8$ unkowns what are the coordinates of $r_1, r_2, r_3, C_4$.

I solved them using the Newton-Raphson multivariate method, with initial guess of $C_4$ being the centroid of $C_1, C_2, C_3$, and initial guess of $r_1, r_2, r_3$ being $\dfrac{2}{3}$ of the way between the initial guess of $C_4$ and $C_1, C_2, C_3$ respectively.

The method converged very quickly, in just $5$ iterations.  The three ellipses I created and the found circle are shown below.

[image]

Comment: What about the "externally" requirement? Is it guaranteed that this initial guess will converge to that instead of an internally tangent circle?

Comment: No.  It is not guaranteed.